# html helpers overloads with razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

```
  @Html.TextBox("displayName", ViewData["cusDispName"], new { @class = "k-textbox", id = "CusMainDispName", disabled = "disabled" })
```

I need help in understanding the above code line with the razor syntax.

especially this line part of code.

`new { @class = "k-textbox", id = "CusMainDispName", disabled = "disabled" })`

this has something to do with CSS, but i couldnt get clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give `@Html.TextBox("displayName", ViewData["cusDispName"], new { @class = "k-textbox", id = "CusMainDispName", disabled = "disabled" })`, when the texbox element is created on your page, it will have the following HTML attributes:

```
class = "k-textbox"
id = "CusMainDispName"
disabled = "disabled"
value = (Whatever you have passed in ViewData["cusDispName"])
name = "displayName"
```

If you only give `@Html.TextBox("displayName", ViewData["cusDispName"])` instead:

```
id = "displayName"
name = "displayName"
value = (Whatever you have passed in ViewData["cusDispName"])
```

The third parameter is a Dictionary containing key - value pairs. The key will be the html attribute you want to set, and the value would be attribute's value.

Comment: what is that new { @class = "k-textbox", id = "CusMainDispName", disabled = "disabled" })

Comment: It is a Dictionary containing key - value pairs. The key will be the html attribute you want to set, and the value would be attribute's value. So in your example, you are passing the class, id, disabled attributes and their values so that they are applied to your textbox element.